# Detecting mouse button usage without events in UWP

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, keyboard, touch

I am remaking my application from Window Forms in UWP Format and the following code doesnt work (I know there is no reason it would because it is a forms thing):

Control.MouseButtons

So I recently used the answer from [Detecting keys pressed without events in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406898/detecting-keys-pressed-without-events-in-uwp/41407075#41407075) to Detect key presses without events in UWP and I was wondering if you could do the same for mouse, controller and touch "activation/usage".

Can you help me?

Either VB.NET or C# (because i can use a code converter).

Thankyou!

Comment: I think you also can use `Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState` and the mouse button's VisualKey is `VirtualKey.LeftButton`.

Comment: @lindexi Thanks that works, what about touch, is it the same? And how do I get the mouse Location?

Comment: @lindexi And the mouse delta?

Comment: I cant find it.

Comment: just to be curious why do you not want to use events?

Comment: @AdityaSharma Because I am making a game and I like to manage my own events and not have to worry about things like If I add a button to the game (Which I would also have to get events from).